# Terminal opening two instances of Sublime instead of one

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

When I'm in the terminal in the appropriate folder I wish to open. I type `subl .` and two instances of Sublime Text comes up.

- If the folder I'm in is the same folder as my last session then I get two instances of the same folder in sublime.
- If I'm in a folder of a different project then my last session then it will pull up the correct folder in sublime and an additional instance of sublime with the last project I was in.

I'd like it to only pull up once with only the directory I'm asking for. Is there a setting somewhere that I have wrong or am I using the wrong command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please type only subl without the period(.), once you are in the appropriate folder you wish to open in the terminal. This will open a single instance of the sublime text.

Comment: @Prabin This doesn't work on sublime text 3

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in `Preferences -> Settings - User`. It worked for me in Sublime Text 3.

```
{
    "hot_exit": false,
    "remember_open_files": false
}
```

But, when we open Sublime Text from dash/search, all the projects/folders from the previous session are removed. You will get a new blank instance of Sublime Text.